# How to read a file when i am redirecting the script to a text file in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am executing a script and redirecting the output to text file  using command sample.sh -base BUG2 1> output.txt 2>&1

now in the script i want to read the contents of the text file to grep some words.so how can we read that text file while the script is running.

Comment: You want to read from the same file you are writing to from within the script? You might want to provide an simplified example of what `sample.sh` is doing. You probably want to keep some sort of state in memory instead of trying to read in what you just wrote out.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it well, you want to execute a script, and redirect its standard output into a file and on standard output: `tee` is what you are looking for.
This command redirect its standard input into a file and on its standard output (http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html)

```
sample.sh -base BUG2 | tee 'file.txt' | more_script
```

Comment: from my sample.sh script I want to read the file.txt so how can that be done while running itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but from what I can guess and assume, it appears that you're trying to read from, and write to the same file.

You will be able to do so, but you won't be able to **rewind**, as Bash can not *seek*.

[Read more](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) on redirections.

---

If you're trying to do something like this: `cat file | sed s/foo/bar/ > file`, i.e. Reading from a file and writing to it in the same pipeline.

That woul'd be impossible.

> You **cannot** read from a file and write to it in the same pipeline. Depending on what your pipeline does, the file may be clobbered (to 0 bytes, or possibly to a number of bytes equal to the size of your operating system's pipeline buffer), or it may grow until it fills the available disk space, or reaches your operating system's file size limitation, or your quota, etc.

( Quoted from [Bash Pitfalls 13](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf13) )